# Initrd : Were can I found the code for real-root-dev

Tags: kernel, boot-loader, initramfs

I'm trying to customize my initrd on kernel 2.4.

At some point, inside the file linuxrc, I have the opportunity to set my root device setting the /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev variable

The example on docs is the one belowe:

```
echo 0x301 > /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev
```

> where 0x301 is for /dev/hda1

What I'm looking for is the code needed for device different form hda1.
I had searched throug  the web by I didn't find an answer, so I hope some of you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this file for your kernel (probably most hasn't even changed over the major kernel versions):

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt